# Genericaly retrieve text value from radio button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to be able to retrieve the text value from a radio button.

For example:

```
first  = Radiobutton(frame, text=name, variable=V, value=0)
second = Radiobutton(frame, text=name, variable=V, value=1)
third  = Radiobutton(frame, text=name, variable=V, value=3)

buttonPressed = V.get()
```

This will give me the value, but I am trying to figure out how to get the
text value. Because my button are created from a generic list of attributes
from an XML doc.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use an `IntVar`, use a `StringVar` instead:

```
>>> root=tkinter.Tk()
>>> V=tkinter.StringVar()
>>> name = "abc"
>>> first = tkinter.Radiobutton(root, text=name, variable=V, value=name)                                                      
>>> first.pack()                                                                                                               
>>> V.get()
'abc'                                                                                                                          
>>>
```

That way, `V.get()` is the same as the `text` for the selected `Radiobutton`.

The other way is to make an list of the `Radiobutton`s, like `[first, second, third]`. Then you can find the `text` by `radiobuttons[V.get()]["text"]`, where the variable `V` is initialized by `IntVar()` (`V = IntVar()`), as the `Radiobutton` can be accessed like a dictionary (equivalent to [`config`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.config-method)) to retrieve the `text` value. However, this does involve maintaining the list.

Comment: thank you so much. I was striving to find such a method like above ( `radiobuttons[V.get()]["text"]` )

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of an attribute of a widget, use the `cget` method:

```
first_text = first.cget("text")
```